# sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I use `chmod a+x /etc/sudoers` in **ubuntu** user which make me regret...

```
ubuntu@VM-250-150-ubuntu:~$ ll /etc/sudoers
-rw-rw--w- 1 root root 781 May  5 11:12 /etc/sudoers
```

And then I can`t use`sudo`

```
ubuntu@VM-250-150-ubuntu:~$ sudo
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I don't have any **root password** so I try `pkexec chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d` to fix it.

But it has another problem,I input the **ubuntu`s password**:

```
ubuntu@VM-250-150-ubuntu:~$ pkexec chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/chmod' as the super user
Authenticating as: ubuntu,,, (ubuntu)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

Friends, can you help me without reinstalling, please? I am regret so much....

And I hope my story can help others. Don`t change the privilege of`/etc`optionally. It`s better to use `sudo visudo` or edit a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [Unix and Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Or the [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) site.